# PHP find value in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 74
                [RecordGUID] => 9BD28E1E-99EB-D4E7-CC2C-AB6F5905BCDA
                [Type] => DENTAL
                [App_Service] => a:4:{i:151;s:6:"AAMCAS";i:152;s:3:"DDS";i:154;s:11:"APP SVC TWO";i:155;s:6:"AADSAS";}
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 73
                [RecordGUID] => A5146CFF-5D17-FB1A-D831-E6835D0A04DD
                [Type] => MED
                [App_Service] => a:1:{i:151;s:6:"AAMCAS";}
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 75
                [RecordGUID] => 0C253109-07E7-151A-0277-19EAC025C2E6
                [Type] => PHYSICAL THERAPY
                [App_Service] => a:1:{i:153;s:8:"PHYSTHER";}
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 155
                [RecordGUID] => 5DF76F3E-2F0C-FD63-B58F-027A61E9BC11
                [AppService] => AADSAS
                [AppService_types] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 151
                [RecordGUID] => 3B503CFC-AB80-C06B-C4C4-8EE548FFC7BF
                [AppService] => AAMCAS
                [AppService_types] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 154
                [RecordGUID] => 753D95F2-6733-AE27-8F2E-48685DC796C0
                [AppService] => APP SVC TWO
                [AppService_types] => 
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 152
                [RecordGUID] => 0D3C9435-64DD-9079-C0F4-D543DFFA0E10
                [AppService] => DDS
                [AppService_types] => 
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 153
                [RecordGUID] => 0D196967-21AF-ADDA-920E-F12938DACADB
                [AppService] => PHYSTHER
                [AppService_types] => 
            )
    )
)
```

I want to find the Type key that equals MED and then grab the App_Service value right below it.

I'm a bit stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not multi-dimensional, it is a nested structure. Arrays are associative i.e. maps in PHP.

To find that value you can do the following (where $x is your array)

```
foreach($x as $entry) {
     foreach($entry as $subentry) {
         if ($subentry['Type'] == "MED") {
             echo $subentry['App_service'];
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified your code a bit and came up with this. foreach ($t as $entry) {
  if ( $entry['Type'] == "MED" ) {
   echo $entry['App_Service'];
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
foreach($MDArray as $array) {
    if(array_key_exists("Type",$array) {
        foreach($array as $k => $v) {
            if($k == "MED") {
                return $array['AppService'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Replace $MDArray with the name of your multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Something simple usually gets the job done.

```
foreach( $array[1] as $find )
{
    if( array_search( 'MED', $find ) )
    {
        echo $find['App_Service'];
    }
}
```

Or, if you prefer a recursive function to check through the entire array:

```
function findRecursive( $type, $array )
{
    foreach( $array as &$section )
    {
        if( is_array( $section ) )
        {
            if( in_array( $type, $section ) )
            {
                return $section['App_Service'];
            }
            elseif( ( $test = findRecursive( $type, $section ) ) !== FALSE )
            {
                return $test;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The function would be useful to reuse for different types and if your array may not have the same format.

**Edit**

Fixed my function. Doesn't require array_search anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If your data can have several arrays with type MED, try the following recursive function:

```
function findByType($array, $val, &$result) {
    foreach ($array AS $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            if (isset($v['Type']) && $v['Type'] == $val) {
                $result[] = $v['App_Service'];
            } else {
                findByType($v, $val, $result);
            }
        }
    }
}

$result = array();
findByType($data, 'MED', $result);
var_dump($result);
```